# Calculate the number of days between 2 dates in Mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Document fields:

```
  {
    "oldDate"   : ISODate("2019-05-13T07:40:23.000Z"),
    "neweDate"  : ISODate("2019-05-14T05:16:27.000Z"),
  }
```

When I add an aggregation pipeline as below;

```
"daysSpent": {
                    "$trunc": {
                        "$divide": [
                            {
                                "$subtract": [
                                    "$newDate",
                                    "$oldDate"
                                ]
                            },
                            1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                        ]
                    }
                }
```

the result is

```
"daysSpent" : 0
```

But I need the result as 1 as these are 2 different days (irrespective of time).

How can I avoid time while finding days between two dates?

Answer (score 1):

You can first find the `timestamp` by subtracting both the dates and then divide the whole equation to get the **days**, **hours**, **minutes**, **seconds**, **milliseconds**.

```
1 hour = 60 minutes = 60 × 60 seconds = 3600 seconds = 3600 × 1000 milliseconds = 3,600,000 ms.
```

Aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "timestamp": {
      "$subtract": [ "$newDate", "$oldDate" ]
    }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "daysSpent": {
      "$trunc": {
        "$ceil": {
          "$abs": {
            "$sum": { "$divide": ["$timestamp", 60 * 1000 * 60 * 24] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zLkHGleYon4)

Comment: @Boat Please check now

Comment: did you verify "oldDate": ISODate("2019-05-15T07:52:06.000Z"),
    "newDate": ISODate("2019-05-15T07:52:09.000Z")  also ? it results 1 instead of 0

Comment: @Boat Yes please check it again.

Comment: Can you please add how many days, hours and minutes between two dates? I've been trying it for some time but idk unable to build logic.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.collection.aggregate( [  
    {
        $addFields: {
        "days": { 
            $trunc : {
                $divide: [{
                    $subtract: ["$newDate","$oldDate"]
                }, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24]
             }
            }
        }    
    },{
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            days: {$toInt: {$cond: {if: {$eq: ["$days", 0]}, then: 1, else: "$days"}}},
            }
        }] )
```

Comment: it does not avoid time. result should be 1 for the example given :  
 "oldDate"   : ISODate("2019-05-13T07:40:23.000Z"),
    "neweDate"  : ISODate("2019-05-14T05:16:27.000Z"),

Comment: Now you can check the above code I edited my old answer

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "daysSpent": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "roundDateNew": {
              "$dateFromParts": {
                "year": {
                  "$year": "$newDate"
                },
                "month": {
                  "$month": "$newDate"
                },
                "day": {
                  "$dayOfMonth": "$newDate"
                }
              }
            },
            "roundDateOld": {
              "$dateFromParts": {
                "year": {
                  "$year": "$oldDate"
                },
                "month": {
                  "$month": "$oldDate"
                },
                "day": {
                  "$dayOfMonth": "$oldDate"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "in": {
            "$divide": [
              {
                "$subtract": [
                  "$$roundDateNew",
                  "$$roundDateOld"
                ]
              },
              86400000
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

above aggregation worked for me.